# when pushing to heroku and getting an error

Tags: heroku-cli, lita

trying push my lita code to heroku but I'm getting this error.

```
❯ git push heroku master                                                                                                                           │
Enumerating objects: 2, done.                                                                                                                      │
Counting objects: 100% (2/2), done.                                                                                                                │
Writing objects: 100% (2/2), 165 bytes | 165.00 KiB/s, done.                                                                                       │
Total 2 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0                                                                                               │
remote: error: pathspec '.' did not match any file(s) known to git.                                                                                │
remote:                                                                                                                                            │
remote: !       Heroku Git error, please try again shortly.                                                                                        │
remote: !       See http://status.heroku.com for current Heroku platform status.                                                                   │
remote: !       If the problem persists, please open a ticket                                                                                      │
remote: !       on https://help.heroku.com/tickets/new                                                                                             │
remote: !       and provide the Request ID 693daaca-96b5-4889-99c9-391d66a59249                                                                    │
remote:                                                                                                                                            │
To https://git.heroku.com/ancient-stream-43362.git                                                                                                 │
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)                                                                                  │
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/ancient-stream-43362.git'
```

I do not know what files that arent known to git.

Comment: Solved, I was in a different branch than the master branch and unless specified  in the heroku push command it will by default look for master branch.

Answer (score 0):

Was in a branch than the master branch and unless specified in the Heroku push command it will by default look for the master branch.